# Get the single column records from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing a bit of problem in retrieving the records from my datatable. Can anybody please offer me any suggestions?

```
Id LearnerId ConnectionId  IsApproved   
3   1            38       1
5   39           1        1 
7   1            31       1 
13  1            30       1 
31  1            40       1 
34  41           1        1 
35  31           1        1 
39  1            42       1
```

This is what my table looks like. I want to use the select query on this table to select the records like the following:

```
AllId
38
39
31
30
40
41
31
42
```

How do I write the query in order to find the above record list? I want to collect all ID's other than 1.

Comment: what columns are included in your final result?  Why does `1` not appear in the final result?

Comment: I need to collect the records according either LearnerId=1 or the ConnectionId =1 and the result will be the single column with no 1 is there only the rest of record will be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `UNION ALL` between two queries. The first will return the `connectionid` values and the second returns the `learnerid` values:

```
select ConnectionId as AllId
from LearnerConnections
where LearnerId = 1
union all
select LearnerId as AllId
from LearnerConnections
where ConnectionId = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9db95/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE LearnerId
            WHEN 1 THEN ConnectionId
            ELSE LearnerId
       END AS AllId
FROM tablename
```

Comment: +1 This will return the example result set, might be what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

```
select  Id
from    YourTable
union all
select  LearnerId
from    YourTable
union all
select  ConnectionId
from    YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Id AS AllId
FROM    YourTable
union all
SELECT  LearnerId AS AllId
FROM        YourTable
union all
SELECT  ConnectionId AS AllId
FROM        YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LearnerId AS AllId FROM tableName
WHERE ConnectionId = 1
UNION
SELECT ConnectionId AS AllId FROM tableName
WHERE LearnerId = 1
```